# Show Video Count Via Json

Tags: php, json, api, youtube-api

So I've been making a dynamic signature with imagecreatepng, The API I'm using is

(Assuming the username is "googlechrome")

http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googlechrome?v=2&alt=json

This line shows me they have 289 videos:

```
{"rel":"http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads","href":"http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/googlechrome/uploads?v=2","countHint":289},
```

I am unsure about how to print it out on the image.

My code so far.

Syntax: domain.com/image.php?channel=googlechrome

yt.png = https://i.stack.imgur.com/XpkDf.png

```
<?php
$channel = $_REQUEST["channel"];
$image = ('yt.png');

$im = imagecreatefrompng($image);

$white = imagecolorallocate($im, 255, 255, 255);
$width = imagesx($im);
$height = imagesy($im);
$font = 2;

$json_output = file_get_contents('http://gdata.youtube.com/feeds/api/users/'.($channel).'?v=2&alt=json');
$json = json_decode($json_output, true);

$username = $json['entry']['yt$username']['$t'];
$view_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['totalUploadViews'];
$sub_count = $json['entry']['yt$statistics']['subscriberCount'];
//$video_count = $json['entry']['DUNNO_YET']['$t'];

$UserName = ("".$username);
imagestring($im, $font, $width-190, $height-59, $UserName, $white);

$viewCount = ("".$view_count);
imagestring($im, $font, $width-190, $height-45, $viewCount, $white);

$subCount = ("".$sub_count);
imagestring($im, $font, $width-190, $height-30, $subCount, $white);

$VideoCount = ("".$video_count);
imagestring($im, $font, $width-190, $height-15, $VideoCount, $white);

//text before counts
$UNAME = ('Username:');
imagestring($im, $font, $width-278, $height-59, $UNAME, $white);
$TOTALVIEWS = ('Total Views: ');
imagestring($im, $font, $width-278, $height-45, $TOTALVIEWS, $white);
$SUBS = ('Subscribers: ');
imagestring($im, $font, $width-278, $height-30, $SUBS, $white);
$TOTALVIDEOS = ('Total Videos: ');
imagestring($im, $font, $width-278, $height-15, $TOTALVIDEOS, $white);

Header('Content-type: image/png');
imagepng($im);
imagedestroy($im);
?>
```

Any Help appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `$video_count` variable should be equal to:

```
$video_count = $json['entry']['gd$feedLink'][6]['countHint'];
```

However, I am unsure if the upload count will always be at the 6th index of `gd$feedLink`, so it may be a smart idea to use something like the following instead:

```
$video_count = 0;
foreach ($json['entry']['gd$feedLink'] as $feed) {
    if ($feed['rel'] == 'http://gdata.youtube.com/schemas/2007#user.uploads') {
        $video_count = $feed['countHint'];
        break;
    }
}
```

Comment: Thanks, Ill stick with the 6th index for now, its been that for a while AFAIK. If it changes it should be editable easily!